# Disabling Ethernet adapter in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, ethernet

I am fairly new to the powershell, I thought tho that it would be a perfect solution for a quick script to disable all network adapters with one click.
I have found [this website](http://msmvps.com/blogs/robfarley/archive/2008/11/18/disable-wifi-with-powershell.aspx) and followed the steps described there.
Everything looked right untill I called `Disable()` function. Here is my script:

```
$lan = get-wmiobject -class Win32_NetworkAdapter -namespace root\CIMV2 | where-object {$_.Name -match "Ethernet"}
$lanEnabled = $lan | % {$_.NetEnabled}
write-host "Ethernet status: " $lanEnabled
if($lanEnabled){
    write-host "Disabling Ethernet"
    $lan | % {$_.Disable()}
}
else{
    write-host "Enabling Ethernet"
    $lan | % {$_.Enable()}
}
```

So `% {$_.NetEnabled}` returns correct status of my Ethernet card. I see in the console all outputs from `write-host`. But the calls to `% {$_.Enable()}` or `% {$_.Disable()}` instead of enabling/disabling just output the following (see lines below 'Disabling Ethernet'):
[image: Script output]

Am I doing something wrong? Like I said I am brand new to the powershell world so I wouldn't be surprised... Thanks for your time and help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Koliat says, the return value means Access Denied. For almost all WMI methods, you need administrative privileges. You need to elevate the PowerShell host as administrator and try it again.

Also, I'd re-write the PowerShell code a bit:

```
$lan = get-wmiobject -query "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE NetEnabled='True' OR NetEnabled='False'"
foreach ($adapter in $lan) {
    Switch ($adapter.NetEnabled) {
        "True" { 
            Write-Host "Disabling adapter ..."
            $adapter.Disable() 
        }
        "False" { 
            Write-Host "Enabling adapter ..."
            $adapter.Enable() 
        }
    }
}
```

When using WMI, the right way of filtering objects is to use the `-Filter` parameter. With `Where-Object`, there is a performance impact. You may not notice it in your example but it is a best practice to use `-Filter` with `Get-WmiObject` cmdlet.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm mistaken, but the performance issue is caused by `Where-object` as it passes a complete query, while WMI `-Filter` causes it to filter out on the fly?

Comment: that is correct. Also, when you use `-Filter`, the filtering happens at the remote system. In case you are using WMI cmdlet to query a remote system, you don't want to transport all the objects over the wire and then filter in the local system.

Comment: I realized that mine didn't work because I had to run it as an Admin. Nevertheless your code is much better, so I will accept it as an answer :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged the question as PowerShell 3 you can use the new NetAdapter cmdlets.

```powershell
Get-NetAdapter | Disable-NetAdapter -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: NetAdapter cmdlets are available only on Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 and onwards.

Answer (score 1):

ReturnValue means "Access is denied".

Please try with admin prompt.

Also, you can check the return values mostly by "net helpmsg 5".

It worked perfectly fine for me.